# Error while installing Scrapy package

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I am trying to install Scrapy package for Python2.7 on win8 machine, but getting the belo error.

```
Downloading/unpacking Twisted>=10.0.0 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading Twisted-14.0.2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (3.1MB)
←[K    100% |################################| 3.1MB 5.8kB/s ta 0:00:01
←[?25hRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): w3lib>=1.8.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\w3lib-1.10.0-py2.7.e
gg (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): queuelib in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\queuelib-1.2.2-py2.7.egg (from
 Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyopenssl-0.14-py2.7.egg (fro
m Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect>=0.9 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cssselect-0.9.1-py2.7.eg
g (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.8.0-py2.7.egg (from Sc
rapy)
Downloading/unpacking zope.interface>=3.6.0 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->Scrapy)
  Downloading zope.interface-4.1.1.tar.gz (864kB)
←[K    59% |###################             | 516kB 1.5kB/s eta 0:03:52  Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/sour
ce/z/zope.interface/zope.interface-4.1.1.tar.gz#md5=edcd5f719c5eb2e18894c4d06e29b6c6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zope.int
erface/) (e6277d288c100478bf348ac91333620f) doesn't match the expected hash edcd5f719c5eb2e18894c4d06e29b6c6!
  Cleaning up...
  Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zope.interface/zope.interface-4.1.1.tar.gz#md5=edcd5f719c5eb2
e18894c4d06e29b6c6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zope.interface/)
```

Please can anyone suggest me something ?

Comment: this looks like some pip issue, which pip version you have? Perhaps package got corrupted when downloading can you try with `pip install -I  zope.interface`? This will redownload and reinstall package, ignoring leftovers from previous failed attempts.

Comment: I've also faced with this problem and my pip version is `7.1.0`